# How do I get the code to read a different row besides 1?

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to take data from a site and paste it in excel.  (suitable super noob project!)

I'm able to get the first row to write properly to excel, BUT, on the excel sheet it just returns the first row (case keenum data) and on the terminal it repeats case keenum's data 250 times.
NO error message.

I tried inserting a "return True" after the append, but it said it needed to be part of a function.  I looked many places, but my scenario is highly unique and i suspect it has to do with my lack of knowledge of the science.

here's my code thus far;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import openpyxl

excel = openpyxl.Workbook()
print(excel.sheetnames)
sheet = excel.active
sheet.title = 'HOF'
print(excel.sheetnames)
sheet.append(['name', 'yards', 'year1', 'year2'])

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/leaders/pass-yds-player-career.html')
    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = any = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
    
    quarterbacks = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    print(len(quarterbacks))

    for quarterback in quarterbacks:
        
        name = soup.find('td', class_="left").a.text
        
        yards = soup.find('td', class_="right").get_text(strip=True)
        
        year1 = soup.find('td', class_="center").get_text(strip=True)
        
        year2 = soup.find('td', class_="center").get_text(strip=True)
        
        print(name,yards,year1,year2)
        sheet.append([name, yards, year1, year2])
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    
excel.save('qbdatascrape.xlsx')
```

Comment: The problem is that, in every loop, you are searching for the very first `td` in the whole document.  Inside the loop, you want `quarterback.find(...)`, not `soup.find(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I would let pandas do that work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    df = pd.read_html('https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/leaders/pass-yds-player-career.html')[0]
    df = df.rename(columns={'Player':'name',
                            'Yds':'yards',
                            'From':'year1',
                            'To':'year2'})
    
    df = df[['name','yards','year1','year2']]

    df.to_excel('qbdatascrape.xlsx', sheet_name='HOF', index=False)
       
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: wow!  very cool!  thank you.  I will turn my gaze towards pandas, that's way easier!

Comment: Yes. Anytime you see a `<table>` tag, and you don't need anything more than the content (Ie, if you need hrefs then go with bs4), just use pandas to parse the table (it uses bs4 under the hood)

Comment: cool!  thank you so much.  I'm so lost, but it is starting to clarify...i know nothing and this is so fun! its so cool how the problems can sometimes be random to me...right now i can't append data to an excel sheet without it skipping to rows then starting to append data, hahahaa, oh well, thanks again!  you rock!

Comment: Ya it is fun. And once it starts making sense, you'll start to enjoy it even more. I remeber being there at the start too...so just hang in there and keep working at it.

Comment: i got an easy one for you if you are open to it?  leme figure out the dm on this platform...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71445196/how-do-i-get-this-code-to-loop-for-other-stocks-for-example-i-want-it-to-repea/74126986#74126986 i felt bad emailing you because i will email a lot, and then i thought maybe this is a good compromise!  he gets stats and recognition and i don't feel bad!  ;-)  im so greatful, you needn't  help anymore, you advanced me like months and many tantrums!